# XPath to select all except common element

Tags: xpath

Say I have a set of XML messages, each with a common header but different types otherwise:

```xml
<MessageType details="test">
    <MessageHeader>
        <HeaderContent>content</HeaderContent>
    </MessageHeader>
    <OtherStuff detail="test"/>
    <MessageContent>
        <MessageText>text</MessageText>
    </MessageContent>
</MessageType>
```

```xml
<MessageType2 details="test2">
    <MessageHeader>
        <HeaderContent>content2</HeaderContent>
    </MessageHeader>
    <MessageContent2>
        <MessageText2>text2</MessageText2>
    </MessageContent2>
</MessageType2>
```

```xml
<MessageType3 details="test3">
    <MessageHeader>
        <HeaderContent>content3</HeaderContent>
    </MessageHeader>
    <OtherStuff3 detail="test3"/>
    <MoreStuff3 detail="test3"/>
    <MessageContent3>
        <MessageText3>text3</MessageText3>
        <AnotherElement><Test text="">text3</Test></AnotherElement>
    </MessageContent3>
</MessageType3>
```

I need an xpath that will select everything except `MessageHeader` and the root element (Because it contains `MessageHeader`).

`//*[not(self::MessageHeader)]` will select everything except `MessageHeader`, but it also selects the root element which I don't want it to do.

I would also settle for something that selects all siblings of `MessageHeader`, because I think that basically does the same thing in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would also settle for something that selects all siblings of MessageHeader

That would be `/*/MessageHeader/following-sibling::*`

But you could also do (in XPath 3.0) `tail(/*/*)` or in XPath 1.0 `(/*/*)[position ()!= 1]`.

Note: if you use `//*`, you're selecting elements deeper in the tree, including for example `HeaderContent`. I think you're probably better off selecting only level-2 elements (children of the outermost element), because you can always navigate downwards from those if you need to. Unlike `//*`, `/*/*` only selects level-2 elements.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for " xpath that will select everything except MessageHeader and the root element" :

```
//*[not(count(ancestor::*)=0) and not(self::MessageHeader)]
```